# LoopbackJS - How to define the entry point for the client application?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to create a loopback project, in which the client application will load in localhost:3000.

So I defined in server/server.js:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
```

Where client is the directory of the frontend files I would like to be presented in localhost:3000.
However, when entering localhost:3000, I still see the message

```
'{"started":"2014-11-17T12:38:58.258Z","uptime":586.385}'
```

instead of index.html.

How can I redirect the entry point from that, to client/index.html?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete '/server/boot/root.js' and it should work

Comment: @Nachi - this is the answer to the question. i know because the op only sees the "started" message because the of the default route set in `/server/boot/root.js`. Once this file is removed, LoopBack will automatically serve '/client/index.html'. thank for info on commenting below their post, i will do that next time i need clarification.